# catching the "Not allowed to load local resource" error in Opera and Safari

Tags: javascript, filesystems, onerror

I use the following Ecmascript to determine if access to local filesystem is allowed:

```
var intranetImg = new Image();
intranetImg.onerror = function(){
    //overide the onclick event for all appropriate links to display:
    alert("please right click & copy link location into your address bar")
}
intranetImg.src = "file://localServer/a/b/testimg.gif"
```

works well in ie 6+, chrome and firefox

I get the "Not allowed to load local resource" error in the console of safari and chrome (ie exactly what I want to know), but the onerror event doesn't fire, and a try/catch block around the assignment of the src attribute does not catch anything either.

Any ideas as to workarounds +/- where the Safari and Opera browser consoles are picking up the error.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the problem? The [`onerror` does fire](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/Qfczg/) on Google Chrome.

Comment: sorry - you are absolutely correct - too many browsers on my machine!! I meant Opera! post edited.